# How to call a dict value with the value given as an input variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
most_used_languages = { 
    1: "Mandarin Chinese", 
    2: "English",
    3: "Hindustani",
    4: "Spanish",
    5: "Arabic",
    6: "Malay",
    7: "Russian",
    8: "Bengali",
    9: "Portuguese",
    10: "French"
}
print("The 10 most popular languages are as follows: ")
print(most_used_languages)
def learn_languageinfo_choice():
    num = int(input("Please enter the corresponding key to the language you would like to learn more about: "))
    for key, value in most_used_languages.items():
        if str(num).isdigit and len(str(num)) > 0 and num < 11 and num > 0:
            print("You chose " +  value(num) + ".")
        else:
            print("You must choose a key that relates to the language of your choice.")
            learn_languageinfo_choice()
learn_languageinfo_choice()
```

**So the main issue that I'm having is that after I define the dictionary, I need to call a value from the dict. using user input.**
Once I collect the input as num, I can't figure out how to call it in the function. Once I figure out that num is a digit and is between 1 and 10, I attempt to continue with the if statement, stating the
 language the user has chosen, but I get hit with this error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I don't really know how to call specific dict values without using for key, value in dict.items():
but if anyone knows a better way, please comment.

Also it looks like if the user input is alphabetical, then I run into the error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

If I can get some explanation that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to iterate `most_used_languages`? Try `print(most_used_languages[num]) if num in most_used_languages else print('Nope!')`

Comment: you don't need `if str(num).isdigit and len(str(num)) > 0 and num < 11 and num > 0:` as you can say `if if str(num) in range(1,11)`

Comment: you need to consider the part of `try/except`

Answer (score 1):

You have too many unnecessary (and incorrect) condition checks. Consider looking up the value in the dictionary directly:

```
def learn_languageinfo_choice():
    num = int(input("Please enter the corresponding key...: "))
    if num in most_used_languages:
        # Note the use of format string
        print(f"You chose {most_used_languages[num]}.")
    else:
        print("You must choose a key...")
```

To make the function really useful, consider also returning the collected value `num` or some sentinel (e.g., -1) for incorrect input.

Finally, your program will still crash (at `int`) if the user inputs a non-integer value. Use `try/except` to avoid the crash.

Comment: i did vote for that answer as it's really clarified all for the OP

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

It's good that you post an error message, but you should also say on which line it occurs.  The full traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack overflow.py", line 25, in <module>
    learn_languageinfo_choice()
  File "stack overflow.py", line 21, in learn_languageinfo_choice
    print("You chose " +  value(num) + ".")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Your problem is that the thing you named `value` is a string.  Strings are not functions.  If you use parentheses, you're trying to call the object you named.  Remove the parentheses to eliminate that error message.  But new error messages appear.

Having said that, you have left us to guess what you want your code to do.  There are a lot of complications which you don't need if your goal is just to look up one language.  Do you really need a dictionary with keys?  What is the purpose of the `for` loop?

This simpler code retrieves one language from the list.  It could still be improved.  My in-line comments may help.

```
languages = ["Mandarin Chinese", "English", "Hindustani",
             "Spanish", "Arabic", "Malay", "Russian",
             "Bengali", "Portuguese", "French"]

print("The 10 most popular languages are as follows: ")
print(languages)

def learn_languageinfo_choice():
    # Note: you can still crash this input statement if you do not
    # enter characters which can be converted to an integer.
    num = int(input("Please enter the corresponding key to the language you would like to learn more about: "))
    if 1 <= num <= len(languages):
        choice = languages[num-1] # lists are indexed starting from zero
        print("You chose " + str(num) + ", " + choice + ".")
    else:
        print("You must choose a key that relates to the language of your choice.")
        learn_languageinfo_choice() # recursion can be hazardous...
    return choice # you defined a function, it should return a valid result

learn_languageinfo_choice()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
most_used_languages = { 
    1: "Mandarin Chinese", 
    2: "English",
    3: "Hindustani",
    4: "Spanish",
    5: "Arabic",
    6: "Malay",
    7: "Russian",
    8: "Bengali",
    9: "Portuguese",
    10: "French"
}

def learn_languageinfo_choice(most_used_languages):
    num = int(input("Please enter the corresponding key to the language you would like to learn more about: "))
    try:
        print(most_used_languages[num])
    except KeyError:
        print('You must choose a key between 1-10 that relates to the language of your choice.')
        learn_languageinfo_choice(most_used_languages)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
most_used_languages = { 
    1: "Mandarin Chinese", 
    2: "English",
    3: "Hindustani",
    4: "Spanish",
    5: "Arabic",
    6: "Malay",
    7: "Russian",
    8: "Bengali",
    9: "Portuguese",
    10: "French"
}
print("The 10 most popular languages are as follows: ")
print(most_used_languages)
def learn_languageinfo_choice():
    num = int(input("Please enter the corresponding key to the language you would like to learn more about: "))
    if str(num).isdigit() and len(str(num)) > 0 and num < 11 and num > 0:
        print("You chose " +  most_used_languages[num] + ".")
    else:
        print("You must choose a key that relates to the language of your choice.")
learn_languageinfo_choice()
```